# Why does Flink's Row object throughput yield much higher performance than Protobuf via Kryo?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Reading [Flink's serialization performance comparison](https://flink.apache.org/2020/04/15/flink-serialization-tuning-vol.-1-choosing-your-serializer-if-you-can/) shows that rows have a much higher throughput than Protobf.

I understand that a rows type is releatively simple, but I am still surprised that protobuf's performance is so "poor" compared as it is also statically typed.

Is that still true in the current iteration of Flink? Or has there been changes to the serialization landscape.

Comment: The Row type has been pretty aggressively optimized. For example, if an operator only accesses one field, only that field will be deserialized. All these tricks add up to made the Row type much more performant.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, but if I were to use tricks like enabling object reuse, it would be theoretically possible to achieve similar performance? Of course this only applies in very specific situations, but wanted to see what other tricks has been pulled for the Row type

Comment: See https://www.ververica.com/blog/a-journey-to-beating-flinks-sql-performance by the same author.